# Multilingual Website not working at server

Tags: php, multilingual

I am working on a multilingual website. I am using php constants for storing multilingual text. I have included these files according to selection of user. I have used utf8 for doctype.Everything is working fine at local end but at server for other language selection it is showing ?????? instead of text. For english everything is fine but for other language (hindi) it is not showing proper text.(only at server ) please help?

Comment: Please post a link if the site is on a public server. It will be easier to identify the problem if I can see the source and HTTP headers.

Comment: Are you using a DB? what's its charset?

Comment: No I am not using DB but using constants in files by defining them

Comment: Are your files utf8? Are the headers of your html files properly configured to say "hey this is an utf-8 html file"?

Comment: yes I have saved files in utf instead of ANSi,UNICODE, UNICODE INDIAN..Also I have used charset = utf8

Comment: @Sam : No sam I am using translation using php constants..

Comment: @SharmaJI Ok only asked as the page source showed the following ( <div id="google_translate_element"> )

Answer (score 0):

I believe that utf-8 supports Hindi, It's possible that the font you are using in the site doesn't have the Hindi characters... Try a different font family and tell us how it went.

Also try adding this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hi">
```

Comment: using webdevelopper, desactivating all CSS doesn't change anything, still "????" => maybe this is an apache configuration problem. Well anyway sounds like a beginner, and a messy server configuration

Comment: Hi Olivier. I think this is the problem. Can you please help me which apache configuration I need to change ?

Comment: I'm sorry I have a few "free time" to help the other ones (for free). Now my "free time" is elapsed, I have to take care of my two children... maybe in 10 hours. Please look at my answers about RewriteRules, I give some advices on "how to setup properly an Apache webserver".

Comment: Yes Olivier , You were right there is something wrong with apache configration of that server. I talked to server guys even they dont know about this. the same code is working fine on another server.